# Compare time in Dialogflow CX conditional response

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I try to compare time in conditional response:

```
if $sys.func.IDENTITY($sys.func.FORMAT_DATE($sys.func.NOW(), "H")) < 8 OR $sys.func.IDENTITY($sys.func.FORMAT_DATE($sys.func.NOW(), "H")) > 20
  We are closed now
else
  We are open
endif
```

Time is 18:20, and I added `$sys.func.IDENTITY($sys.func.FORMAT_DATE($sys.func.NOW(), "H"))` to the text output and made sure it says "18", but it keeps saying "We are closed now".

I see that "18" is of string type. I might need to convert the value to integer, but how?

Working hours are between 8am-9pm

How to properly compare?

Comment: Have you tried changing the symbols `<`, `>` like `$sys.func.IDENTITY($sys.func.FORMAT_DATE($sys.func.NOW(), "H")) > 8 OR $sys.func.IDENTITY($sys.func.FORMAT_DATE($sys.func.NOW(), "H")) < 20` ?

Comment: @JoseGutierrezPaliza I tried, but it does not work either. I checked the detailed response and I see that "18" is a string, not an integer. Hence I believe I can't compare properly for < > with a number, I don't know how to cast this string to integert or how to get integer out of time object

Comment: @righaway717 I wanted to make sure that you were getting the Hour correctly because changing the symbols would mean that it should enter the else. Now that you said that it brings you “18” as a string, let me  post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right hand side is [type casted to the same type](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/condition#:%7E:text=The%20right%20hand%20side%20is%20type%20casted%20to%20the%20same%20type%20as%20the%20left%20hand%20side%20before%20comparing) as the left hand side before comparing.

Said this, I think that you can use “HH” to make sure you have a leading zero, since there could be a non-numeric “:mm” minute part.

You can use the following code:

```
if $sys.func.FORMAT_DATE($sys.func.NOW(), "HH") < “08” OR $sys.func.FORMAT_DATE($sys.func.NOW(), "HH") > “20” 
  We are closed now 
else 
  We are open 
endif
```

Comment: Though I already used webhook to make comparison using javascript, I checked your answer and it worked. Thank you. Though as far as I understand, the solution works because comparing numbers as strings work pretty much the same in this case. But I believe I can just swap the positions of number and string in condition and compare as integers. Have not tried though, just came to my mind